# Same SQL Server 2012 tolerates backward SQL syntax depending on which database is in use?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have encountered a situation where an SQL Server 2012 seems to tolerate SQL syntax e.g. for adding DATETIMEs to DATEs (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440917/add-datetime-and-time)) depending on which database is in use.

Could this be the case, and if so what determines the amount of backward compatibility that is tolerated by the same server in such cases. For instance, does it depend on who (which server) originally created the database?

Comment: Without knowing the details, this sounds like something controlled by the SQL Server compatibility level:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This was spot on: compatibility level 90 vs. 110. If you want to copy your comment into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it and be done with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server functionality is controlled not only by the version of the software but also by the compatibility level system parameter.  Using the right compatibility level, the new software can be made to behave like older software.  (Microsoft has not yet figured out how to make older software work like newer software; perhaps they are working on that. ;)

So, when things aren't working, but they should be, that is one of the first things to suspect.  More information on the settings and changing them is in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx).