# Add Time To Date

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, datetime

How can I add Time, like `08:14:13`, to a date like `01/01/2014 00:00:00` using [TSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) or VB.NET without using `concat`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL to add datetime field with a time field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228132/tsql-to-add-datetime-field-with-a-time-field).

Comment: please share your code because it sounds like there might be other issues

Comment: And please specify what types they currently are

Comment: I have putted the result of this request `set language 'french';SELECT DATEADD(dd,0, (Select DATEDIFF(dd,0, (select MAX(HeurMsg) from ib2new` in a datetime variable and I want to add it to this variable `Dim resultTimer = DateAdd("n", TimeToAdd, Date.Parse(Vpreouv))`

Comment: convert `Vpreouv` to a TimeSpan and then `result = baseDate.Add(vpreouvTimeSpan)` should work.  The NET DateTime type will add a TimeSpan type to a date;  that is not the same thing as *setting* the time to a specific value though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim Vpreouv As String = "01/01/2014"
Dim TimeToAdd As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("08:14:13")

Dim resultTimer as DateTime = _
Date.Parse(Vpreouv).Add(New TimeSpan(TimeToAdd.Hour, TimeToAdd.Minute, TimeToAdd.Second)
```

This code does what you want in one line given the variables initialized as described.  I've tested this and resultTimer contains 01/01/2014 08:14:13.